# How to enable selecting in GridView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which is bind to a DataTable, how can I enable row selection based on ID, if there is no such a think how can I select a row from based on ID? 
To clarify more 
I have gridview that display ID and Names from DataTable:

```
 ID    |   Name 
 1     |    Jad
 2     |    Lara
```

I want to select a row from it, like the first and get its ID.

Comment: you can use template with check box control for selecting any rows

Comment: Can you show me an example, I want to be able to get the value of ID?

Comment: paste your code what you tried?

Comment: You want to get the `ID` of whatever has been selected or you want to simulate a user click and use the `ID` as criteria ?

Comment: I want get the id of the selected row, in example if jad selected I want to get his ID which is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox Text="text" runat="server" val ='<%#Eval("ID")%>' AutoPostBack ="true" OnCheckedChanged="Unnamed_CheckedChanged" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Server side

```
 protected void Unnamed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((sender as CheckBox).Attributes["val"]);
    }
```

Comment: I still cannot get the ID, it doesn't write any value

Comment: even when I try to print any other text inside the method I got no thing